# Laravel: Can I somehow shorten this url with json encoded parameter?

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

I have an AJAX request to grab some values from database and then redirect back to page with those values so I can use them on page.

The thing is that this URL is very long:

```
http://ibpc.dev/admin/products/create?specifications={%22id%22:4,%22title%22:%22Video%20Cards%22,%22created_at%22:null,%22updated_at%22:null,%22specifications%22:[{%22id%22:1,%22name%22:%22Model%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22pivot%22:{%22category_id%22:4,%22specification_id%22:1},%22attributes%22:[{%22id%22:1,%22specification_id%22:1,%22name%22:%22Brand%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22}]},{%22id%22:2,%22name%22:%22Interface%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22pivot%22:{%22category_id%22:4,%22specification_id%22:2},%22attributes%22:[{%22id%22:2,%22specification_id%22:2,%22name%22:%22Interface%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22}]},{%22id%22:3,%22name%22:%22Chipset%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22pivot%22:{%22category_id%22:4,%22specification_id%22:3},%22attributes%22:[{%22id%22:3,%22specification_id%22:3,%22name%22:%22Chipset%20Manufacturer%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22},{%22id%22:4,%22specification_id%22:3,%22name%22:%22GPU%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22},{%22id%22:5,%22specification_id%22:3,%22name%22:%22Core%20Clock%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22}]},{%22id%22:4,%22name%22:%22Memory%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22pivot%22:{%22category_id%22:4,%22specification_id%22:4},%22attributes%22:[{%22id%22:6,%22specification_id%22:4,%22name%22:%22Effective%20Memory%20Clock%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22},{%22id%22:7,%22specification_id%22:4,%22name%22:%22Memory%20Size%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22},{%22id%22:8,%22specification_id%22:4,%22name%22:%22Memory%20Interface%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22},{%22id%22:9,%22specification_id%22:4,%22name%22:%22Memory%20Type%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:05%22}]},{%22id%22:5,%22name%22:%22Ports%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22pivot%22:{%22category_id%22:4,%22specification_id%22:5},%22attributes%22:[]},{%22id%22:6,%22name%22:%22Details%22,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-23%2022:54:04%22,%22pivot%22:{%22category_id%22:4,%22specification_id%22:6},%22attributes%22:[]}]}
```

Can I somehow shorten this URL?

AJAX GET request from template:

```
('#category-select').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/admin/catalog/specifications',

        data: {
            selectFieldValue: $(this).val()
        },

        success: function (response) {
            window.location.href = response.redirectUrl + response.data;
        }
    });
});
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/products/create', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getCreateProduct',
    'as' => 'admin.getCreateProduct'
]);

Route::get('/admin/products/create/{specifications}', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getCreateProduct',
    'as' => 'admin.getCreateProduct'
]);

Route::get('/admin/catalog/specifications', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getProductSpecifications',
    'as' => 'admin.getProductSpecifications'
]);
```

AdminController:

```
public function getCreateProduct(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    if ($request['specifications']) {
        $specifications = json_decode($request['specifications']);
    } else {
        $specifications = null;
    }

    return view('admin.products.create', ['categories' => $categories, 'specifications' => $specifications]);
}

public function getProductSpecifications(Request $request)
{
    $categoryId = $request['selectFieldValue'];

    $specifications = Category::with('specifications.attributes')->find($categoryId);

    return response()->json(array('data' => json_encode($specifications), 'redirectUrl'=> '/admin/products/create?specifications='), 200);
}
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting the user to another page with the JSON in the URL, is it not possible to just return the JSON response from getProductSpecifications() and parse it in the success function in AJAX?

Comment: @TobyMellor I am generating new html elements based on that response value. i need to "reload" the page for that. Or can I do that without reloading it?

Comment: What I would do is create empty hidden HTML elements, and once the response has been returned in the success function, you just fill in the empty elements and unhide them all. Without seeing the code, I can't tell though.

Comment: @TobyMellor Problem is that I don't know how many elements I will have. I am creating form inputs based on the response e.g. user picks smartphone category and I create section Screen and then inputs for Size and Resolution, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't a POST be a better option for this sort of data set? Unless you actually want to cache the result set and call it directly, the use of a POST allows you add all sorts of parameters. Plus, your not breaking RESTful state since the search result is technically a new object.

Comment: yeah @Jason right, if you need to pass many param to the URL, its better to use POST instead of GET.

Comment: If for some reason you can't use POST, maybe you could encode it? It would still be long but it would maybe be more manageable.